# Shared Preferences Crashes Program

Tags: java, android, debugging, crash-reports

Im trying to make a world creator in a list view that saves the world's name. But the shaed preferences causes the program to crash before the activity opens. Why is this happening? It is perfectly fine without the shared preferences. Any ideas? (that on list view click is unfinished, don't worry about that.) The errors that were most notable were the null pointerexception at the array adapter, storage == null, and skipped frames

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class WorldMenu extends  ListActivity{
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String splitter;
    String[] worldList;
    PopupWindow worldNamer;
    Drawable background;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(WorldMenu.this,                             
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, worldList));
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("worldString", 0);
        splitter =  "Create World\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" + 
            prefs.getString("worldString", "No worlds found.");
        worldList = splitter.split("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
     }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(position == 0){
            worldNamer = new PopupWindow(this);
            worldNamer.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what does the stack trace say, *exactly*? Your "errors that were most notable" sentence is particularly unclear...

Comment: Please use spaces rather than tabs to format your code in future, btw.

Comment: ok i will do so next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the shared preferences and the array for the list view under the adapter so the list view couldn't be created in the first place. Just put the variables on top of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity try followed Preferences init:

```
private SharedPreferences pref = null;

...

pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String worldString= prefs.getString("worldString", "No worlds found.");

...
```